# Checking for double booking in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

Ok, my project to create an event organizer for a music contest. Basically I take input data such as a list of about 400 entries and I output into a few separate excel sheets by room number and type. The problem is, when assigning events to an array, (I have a separate array for each room and all the arrays are contained in a list) I need to check and fix if accompanists are double booked for the same time slot. Or essentially, if two different arrays have the same accompanist value for array[i]

Ideas? Please try to explain well, I'm self taught with only a bit of experience

```
    private void assignEvents()
    {
    // assign every event in order
    // check accompanists for no double-books
        foreach (Event[] room in roomList)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Event ev in eventList)
            {
                if (ev.Type == room[0].Type)
                {
                    room[i] = ev;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not do a LINQ GroupBy query off a composite room + time key, and then find all groups where the count is greater than 1? That would tell you if you have any double bookings.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with LINQ like Tejs suggests, but I would go another route since you are designing an organizer and you will probably need the extra information any way (for example, to display the schedule of an accompanist). I would have a list of all accompanists with a sorted array of all of their bookings (basically , their schedule). You can then have a function to check for every new booking whether there is a conflict (in the booking array) for each of the accompanists in the booking and if not, continue by adding the booking to the accompanists' schedule

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you must compare values per column. I suggest to create your own `RoomList` collection class by deriving it from your actual collection type and to add it the possibility to iterate columns

```
public class RoomList : List<Event[]>
{
    public IEnumerable<Event> TimeSlot(int columnIndex)
    {
        foreach (Event[] events in this) {
            if (events != null && columnIndex < events.Length) {
                yield return events[columnIndex];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use LINQ to get double bookings

```
RoomList roomList = new RoomList();
// ...
for (int slot = 0; slot < roomList[0].Length; slot++) {
    var doubleBooked = roomList.TimeSlot(slot)
        .GroupBy(e => e.Type)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
    if (doubleBooked.Any()) {
        Console.WriteLine("Doubly booked accompanists in slot {0}", slot);
        foreach (var accompanistGroup in doubleBooked) {
            Console.WriteLine("    {0}", accompanistGroup.Key);
        }
    }
}
```